Understanding the application of residue theorem to the evaluation of the improper integral of $\sin(x)\over x(x^2+a^2)$.

I understand everything so far except for the step circled in red. It just seemingly comes out of nowhere. I have no Idea where to begin proving it. Any help would be appreciated.

what's not clear? The first or the second equality?

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Have you tried working out the line integral yourself using the parametrization $z = \varepsilon e^{it}$, where $t$ goes from $\pi$ to $0$?

@SineoftheTime the first one, but funny enough, your comment made me realize the first equality is trivial. So thanks I guess.

@SineoftheTime the first equality isn't rigorous though. 1/z blows up to infinity, so how do we know that the error in the "basically 1" term doesn't become significant due to multiplying a giant term?

Did you try parametrizing $\gamma_{\varepsilon}$?

With or without complex analysis, don't you think that it could be simpler to write $$\frac{1}{x \left(x^2+a^2\right)}=\frac 1 {a^2}\Big( \frac{1}{x} -\frac{1}{2 (x-i a)}-\frac{1}{2 (x+i   a)}    \Big)$$
